# php file to php array to js array - as array of arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mysqli

```
...
$php_array = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var location = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

How can I modify the above code that gives me this output (an array of objects methinks?)

```
var javascript_array = [
    {"city":"Hermosa Beach","lat":"33.860069","lng":"-118.398784"},
    {"city":"San Jose","lat":"34.694628","lng":"-118.398784"},
    .... ]
```

to give me this...  (an array of arrays?)

```
var javascript_array = [
    ["Hermosa Beach",33.860069,-118.398784],
    ["San Jose",34.694628",-118.398784],
    .... ]
```

without a bunch of foreaching's...

Comment: check out this documentation on how to transfer between php and javascript: http://cullenwebservices.com/how-to-pass-an-object-from-php-to-javascript-and-back-again-using-json/

Comment: @jordan.peoples His question isn't how to transfer between php and JS, it's how to change the structure of his array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MYSQLI_NUM` instead of `MYSQL_ASSOC` when you call `mysqli_fetch_all()`. Then the rows will be indexed arrays instead of associative arrays.

Although I don't know why you would want the array to be like this. Arrays should be used for uniform data, objects should be used for heterogeneous data.

Answer (score 1):

thanks, this works and is very lean...

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM file";
    $result = $con->query($query);

    // Fetch all rows and return the result-set as an associative array:
    // using numeric keys for the array, instead of creating an associative array.
    $php_array = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
?>  

<script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php

    // create a JSON representation of a value that javascript will understand
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);

    // dump json object into javascript variable 'locations'
    echo "var locations =" .  $js_array . ";\n";
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: BTW: In JavaScript everything is an object and no it is NOT very clean

Comment: why do you say not clean?

Comment: php tag inside script tag? Really? Consider separate client code and server code. As said before, to communicate between them, use the technics that are thought for that

Comment: Lean as in lacking "unnecessary code and functionality". True that mixing PHP in javascript is not very orthodox. I will use Ajax call and that will illiminate the issue, but I was working up the model piece by piece trying understand PHP/javascript array/object interaction.

Comment: Final comment: Don't post that kind of testing code here, please. Posting your own FINAL solution to the problem is fine and even encouraged!

Comment: He is asking a specific question not advice on client server solutions. Answer responds to question. Don't see what your problem is.